# Refresh page on load once

Tags: php, javascript, html

this should be so simple but I can't get it to work, all I want to do is to refresh my page immediately once when it is loaded.  I don't want to stop caching as much of the data on my site stays the same.  I don't want to go to a different url i.e. www.mysite.com/page1.php?refreshedpage because my url's are clean and easy to follow.

I have images using the same file name which get changed, hence when a user accesses my site, they see the old cached images.

Cheers

Comment: `but I can't get it to work`, what is it that you can't? code please

Comment: I can't really think of any good reason why you would want to do this.

Comment: Making the site refresh, so that images are reloaded is both bad practice and is not 100% reliable.  Browsers like Opera will just continue to use the cache.

Comment: If this helped, please give me the answer credit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your images something like the following:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg?refresh=20110524" />
```

I just used the date, but you can use whatever you want.
This will trigger the browser to think it is a new image, and will download it, instead of using the cache, for all users.

No matter what querystring you use, after the image file name, it will still load the same image, although the browser will think it's a different image.